# Retrieve multiple fields in a single request with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Upon user registration I fetch the users data (name, birthday, location, etc) and also the users profile image.

Currently, I would be able to do this: `/me?fields=picture,name`, but the picture returned is too low resolution, so I'd like to fetch the picture with the height parameter (as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture)).

My only option, as I see it, is to part it up in two requests, which seems inefficient:

- Get user data `me/?fields=name`
- Get user picture `me/picture?height=500&redirect=false`

Would there be a way to merge this into ONE request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **field expansion**, just one API call:

```
/me?fields=name,picture.width(500).height(500),birthday
```

API Explorer test: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cpicture.width%28500%29.height%28500%29&version=v2.2

More information about field expansion: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fieldexpansion

---

[Batch Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/batch-requests/) would be another solution, although not a very good one in that case because they are a lot more complicated (more code, more things to consider) and they don´t count as one call:

> each call within the batch is counted separately for the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits

...meaning, they are only faster than 2 separate calls (as fast as the slowest call in the batch), but field expansion is really just 1 call. Batch Requests are for "potentially unrelated Graph API calls".

Comment: may i ask why the downvote? i am happy to improve my answer, but i don´t think there is any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `batch` as per the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests)

Here's an example request for your needs:

URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/

POST data (important! not GET!):

`batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/?fields=name"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/picture?height=500&redirect=false"}]`

Optional but recommended: `include_headers=false`

Example response:

```
[
  {
    "code": 200,
    "body": "{\n \"name\": \"Richard Down\",\n \"id\": \"704787476294950\"\n}"
  },
  {
    "code": 200,
    "body": "{\n \"data\": {\n \"height\": 604,\n \"is_silhouette\": true,\n \"url\": \"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/t31.0-1/s960x960/10506738_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_o.jpg\",\n \"width\": 960\n }\n}"
  }
]
```

EDIT: As you've tagged this with [facebook-php-sdk](/questions/tagged/facebook-php-sdk), here's an example using that:

```
$requests = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => 'me/?fields=name'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => 'me/picture?height=500&redirect=false')
);

$response = json_decode($facebook->api('?batch=' . json_encode($requests), 'POST'), true);

$name = $response[0]['name'];
$image = $response[1]['url'];
```

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to use `field expansion`, as per described by Luschn, but +1 for the PHP code example and the nice workaround.